# Apple Auto Renewal In-App Purchase Expiry Time

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am making an app with auto renew in-app purchase. It is my first time with this api so I am bit confused about the auto renewal logics.
Would be grateful if you guys can help me with these 2 logics-
1) When a user buys a new subscription, does the expiry equal to the date or date/time.
For example - I buy a subscription for a month today at 2.00pm. Will it expire next month at 2.00pm or at midnight. Means it just renew the subscription by date or by the time you purchase it.

2) During Auto renewal, as mentioned in apple docs, apple starts trying to renew the subscription 24 hours before the expiry date. If the user somehow cancels auto renewal between these 24 hours will apple still renew his subscription or the cancellation will take affect immediately (assuming his subscription hasn't already been renewed).

please somebody answer it. Thanks a lot in advance.